# Multiple records inside <td> id sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am pushing multiple record to the table data by using  id. Problem is its fetching only last record.

**Inside the controller**

```
for(var i=0;i<globalval.length;i++){
        console.log("Inside for loop --->"+globalval[i].v1); -- > working
        Ext.get('customerinfo').setHtml(globalval[i].v1);
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
itemTpl:[

'<tr class="tbl">'
   + '<td id="customerinfo"></td></tr>'
+'</table>'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you are doing is that you have an array but in `itemTpl` , you have not placed your XTemplate inside a loop. Do it like this:

```
itemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',       // process the array
        place your tpl structure here..
    '</tpl>
);
```

------------------------------------------ EDITED -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

For example if the object from which you are supposed to fetch data is `tableData` then iterate like this:

```
'<tpl for="tableData">',
        '{name}: {value}, '
'</tpl>'
```

Comment: This is normal iteration. I am using arrayobject.. how to iterate that inside itemtpl. this could be suitable if i have store. but i am not using store

Comment: It is not necessary to use store, but you have to set some data or have to have some data there. And even if it is array object, it should work.See edited answer.

Comment: Send me your view, store and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a single cell (customerinfo) with the value of each record. Problem is that it's one single cell. It's like saying a = 1, then a = 2, then a = 3. Obviously at the end, a = 3.

Comment: I'm in a real hurry right now, but as an idea, use Ext.XTemplate (check documentation for it). If you can't figure it out, i'll help you tomorrow. Sorry :)